# Angular2 rc.6 with google-maps and jspm / systemjs can't seem to point to core.umd

Tags: google-maps, angular, jspm

Using angular2 and jspm I can't seem to point to the new google maps main file: core.umd.js (systemjs keep on trying to load core.js instead of core.umd.js)

google maps project: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps core.umd

if I manually copy core.umd.js > core.js all is well... (but that's not a solution of course).

my setup is:

````
map: {
        "angular2-google-maps": "npm:angular2-google-maps@0.14.0/core",

```
packages: {
        "StudioDashboard": {
            "main": "StudioDashboard.js"
        },
        "angular2-google-maps": {
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
````

for the complete config see:
https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/jspm.config.js

any suggestions are appreciated,

regards

Sean

Answer (score 0):

You should change `map` to below, so that it will `core.umd` as source.

```
map: {
   "angular2-google-maps": "npm:angular2-google-maps@0.14.0/core.umd"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes that was the first thing I tried, but when I do that I get an error of ```GET http://localhost:9089/jspm_packages/npm/angular2-google-maps@0.14.0/core.umd/core.js 404 (Not Found)``` so it's appending .umd to the directory instead of the file (should of added it in my initial question, sorry).